# Need SQL Query to find Min Row of Current year compared to min Row of Last Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below audit table. Need to find Min Row where year is Year Getdate()) compared to min Row where Year is Year(getdate())-1

[image: |Audit Id|Date|id]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function `PARTITION BY` ID &  year of the date column.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,YEAR(Date) ORDER BY Date) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```